# How to test a variable if it changes or not? Python

Tags: python, arcmap

I am quite new to python.

Roughly i want to do the following:

```
var=0
while x doesn't change
   return var

   if x changes
      var = var + 1
```

This shall then be continued until all x-values are processed. I don't have a list of the x-values.

Any suggestions how to get from my ideas to code?

I am working in field calculator in Arcmap.

Answer (score 0):

```
y = x
while x == y:
    # your code that might change x
```

Comment: ofc it depends on what "changes" mean in the first place - if it is a new member in an array, this does not work.

Comment: well it is a column in a table. as long as the attribute is constant, i want to add to another column of the tabel the value 1. if the column value changes, i want to add to the other column to value 2. and so on...

Answer (score 0):

```
def edgedetector(it):
    var = 0
    old_i = object() # guaranteed to be different from everything else
    for i in it:
        if i != old_i:
            var += 1
            old_i = i
        yield var
```

Having this generator function, you do the following:

Supposed you have an iterable `it` having the values you are interested in, you do

```
import itertools
it_a, it_b = itertools.tee(it) # split it up
for items, val in itertools.izip(it_a, edgedetector(it_b)):
    #do whatever you want to do with it
```

Alternative:

```
def edgedetector(it):
    var = 0
    old_i = object() # guaranteed to be different from everything else
    for i in it:
        if i != old_i:
            var += 1
            old_i = i
        yield i, var # this is changed...
```

makes it easier:

```
for items, val in edgedetector(it):
    #do whatever you want to do with it
```

`object()` is the instantiation of an instance of the class `object`. The generator function uses it to detect the inequality of the initial "old" object with the first element of the iterable.

Comment: Thank you for the code! However I only get NULL values in return. The code works though. What could cause this?

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed explanation. Yet i only get NULL values as results. Any more ideas. I really don't know much about python.

Comment: @user1738154 Where exactly do you get the NULL values? (Or rather `None` values?)